# Ошибка с кодировкой HTML

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, кодировка

Написал небольшое веб-приложение на реакте, которое редактирует в HTML шаблоне данные, и на стороне клиента создает новый HTML файл с введенными данными, который впоследствии загружается вручную в Outlook как подпись к письмам. Однако возникают следующие проблемы: title у index.html вместо русских букв состоит из иероглифов. Сохраняемый файл выглядит корректно только с английским текстом, русский опять же преобразовывается в иероглифы. В VS Code, Outlook стоит кодировка UTF-8. Проверил, что именно перезапись файла портит все русские символы в нем. Как можно починить?

Менял кодировку в VS Code, в Outlook - ничего не помогало. Предполагаю что это происходит из-за конвертации изначального HTML в JSX и потом снова обратно.

Comment: код проекта на [Github](https://github.com/restgoss/signature-generator)

Comment: У вас в index.html через тег `meta` задана кодировка **utf-8** ( причём в двух местах ), однако сам файл сохранён в кодировке **Windows-1251**. Не пробовали менять "utf-8" на "windows-1251"?

Comment: @DungyBug Спасибо большое за ответ! да, только что поменял - не помогло, и до этого тоже пробовал. Однако заметил, что если пересохранить созданный html файл и изменить кодировку на любую кириллическую - через раз помогает. Проблему к сожалению не решает(

Comment: Кракозябры вместо русских символов могут возникать только если файл сохраняется в **windows-1251**, а открывается в **utf-8**. Вы можете попробовать сохранять файл всегда в **utf-8**, либо открывать его исключительно в **windows-1251**. Больше ничего предложить не могу пока...

Comment: @DungyBug в браузере проблема решилась, отображается созданный русский текст корректно, однако при импорте в Outlook появляются проблемы. Кстати проблема в браузере исчезла, когда убрал явное присвоение кодировки генерируемому файлу...